# CSS3 Flip Card with Automatic Height

Tags: jquery, css, height

I'm using a tutorial to create a flip card effect using CSS3 and jQuery and I'm having issues getting the height to adjust to the content length while having it still flip on the center horizontal.

**[FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/GDdtS/1100/)**

Code:

```
<div class="flip"> 
    <div class="card"> 
        <div class="face front"> 
            Front<br> Other text.<br> Other text.<br> Other text.<br> Other text.
        </div> 

        <div class="face back"> 
            Back
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

---

```
body {
 background: #ccc;   
}
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
  z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flip .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}​
```

---

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('flipped');
    });
    return false;
});​
```

​

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a working solution on **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVsR5/2/)**.

JS:

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped');
    return false;
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.flip > .card').removeClass('flipped');
});

var frontHeight = $('.front').outerHeight();
var backHeight = $('.back').outerHeight();

if (frontHeight > backHeight) {
    $('.flip, .back').height(frontHeight);
}
else if (frontHeight > backHeight) {
    $('.flip, .front').height(backHeight);
}
else {
    $('.flip').height(backHeight);
}
```

A defined height isn't flexible, so what you're seeing is what you've defined. Since the height will not remain constant, the front or the back needs to have a defined height that matches whichever element is the tallest. In the example, `.front` is taller, so `.back` is updated to have the same height, allowing you to achieve the vertical flip effect at the center.

In your example, the `mouseleave` event can fire while the elements during the animation. I have assumed that you did not want this to occur, so I've updated the logic to remove `.flipped` when leaving the card, which retains its height throughout the animation. I also cleaned up the CSS to be less redundant. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. One question though. I seem to be getting a different animation when there is just one line of text. Granted this will probably never be an issue where I'm using it, is there a way to fix this so that the behavior is the same as with multiple lines?

Comment: I hadn't even tried it with one line, but I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: As I said, it's unlikely to occur, but I just wasn't sure why it was different.

Comment: I've updated the example url. The `.flip` container needs a defined height as well, and when the heights are the same, only that element should be updated.

Comment: Perfect! Great work. I've been toying with the height attributes for an hour trying to figure it out. I knew the fixed height definition was a problem, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it. Many many thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work in FF 21.0 for Mac. It just shows the back and won't flip.

Comment: @Sortofabeginner The `-moz` prefix is needed on some of the CSS3 properties. I haven't spent the time to determine which, so here's the above fiddle updated with `-moz` prefixed properties: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVsR5/82/)

Answer (score 23):

You can trick it, by making the .back position absolute and 100% height. And leave the .front position relative.

```
.front  {position: relative;}
.back       {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Note, might be useful in some scenarios: add 2 additional elements to the back, for header and footer, and make the footer position absolute and set it to bottom 0.

Comment: Nice little hack for this particular use!

Comment: What if the back is larger than the front?

Comment: If the back is consistently going to be larger than the front, then you can just swap the attributes given above (i.e.: simply `.back  {position: relative;} .front {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}`) If you do not know which one is going to be bigger then it seems we're down to testing with JavaScript (can add a wrapper to the content of each face and measure that.)